# Security For URL'S Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, security, laravel-5.1

I am developing an application in laravel 5.1, I have multiple users but they have different permits and when you log in you can edit for example your account and the route is app/user/1/edit but if the user change the id app/user/2/edit he can edit the information of other user, is there a way to protect the URL? Thanks :D

Comment: are you still looking for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solutions would be putting middleware on that route and comparing logged users id with the one in URL (for all routes actually, viewing, editing etc)
Another one would be using user/edit instead and getting id directly from session data, and I would recommend that

---

Of course you still have to make sure that nobody can just post another id, so middleware OR getting user id from session instead of POST to save